# Save installed Epson Stylus SX130 driver(s) on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, printing

I've installed the printer just by plugging the usb cable in. It was installed automatically and works fine with printing. I didn't try scanning, yet.

**Can the driver(s) be saved on hard disk or be extracted manually from the Ubuntu OS** for the case that it's/they're not provided any more in future, when needed, for example after an upgrade?

What's it like in general regarding device drivers for Linux? **Does a working driver only work for a specific or for all Ubuntu versions (16.04, 18.04...) or also for Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu... or even for all Linux versions (Debian, Mint...)?**

**Where can be displayed which driver is currently installed, because in [System Settings] [Printer] [Properties] I didn't find anything on that?**

Comment: I added information on currently installed drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download drivers from https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

For Ubuntu you will need a deb package. `amd64` for a 64-but system, or `i386` for a 32-bit one.

The drivers should install on Ubuntu flavors, Debian and Mint, but it is not guaranteed that they will work with future Ubuntu version.

The esiaest way to see the driver installed is to go to `http://localhost:631` in your bowser.

Go to Administration -> Printer Management and you'll see which driver is installed.

You can also see all Epson related packages installed by running in a terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep epson
```

`epson-inkjet-printer-escpr` is the driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you noticed, I edited my question. Could you tell me about the Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu... issue?

Comment: Ubuntu flavors mean:  Xubuntu, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, etc. All should work.

Comment: I've got the german language package. Where is "Administration" -> "Printer Management" on my system or how do the icons look like? In the german package there are "Systemeinstellungen" (in the starter bar) and "Drucker" which means "System Settings" and "Printer".

Comment: Enter `localhost:631` in your internet BROWSER.

Comment: Thanks. A "CUPS 2.1.3" splash screen appeared. Is "CUPS 2.1.3" the currently installed driver or only a printer management software?

Comment: Maybe there was a misunderstanding and I didn't get it right! Do you mean going to "Administration" -> "Printer Management" **within** CUPS? There's "CUPS for Administrators" and "Managing Operation Policies". Is that correct?

Comment: There must be a menu on top of the screen. The second from the left is Administration. The last one is "Printers". You can click that one to see the driver.

Comment: I think I'm at the right location now. Why doesn't there appear a filename (like .sys in Windows)? Not to get me wrong, I'm not a friend of Windows but this is all completely different and new to me. What is CUPS, actually? Do I have access to it directly from the desktop screen? Is it part of my Ubuntu installation and integrated in the OS although it's run from the browser? Questions over questions! Although I'm not new at Ubuntu I'm still a beginner and only scratching the surface without knowing what's underneith!

Comment: There is are no file names, becuase there is nothing useful you can do with the files. In Ubuntu you deal with packages. The driver is installed locally. I am adding some other information regarding how to see installed packages.

Comment: I ran the terminal command line. Is epson-inkjet-printer-201101w the driver?

Comment: Yes, it is a driver. And it is the correct oneas the file from Epson site is `epson-inkjet-printer-201101w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb`

Comment: You gave me a lot of information! But the more answers I get the more questions I have, too. Anyway. I'm going to download the driver by your link above. If you like to review the conversation and if there's still something you can tell me (because this is all very interesting to me) I'd be glad. Thank you very, very much!

Comment: You have installed exactly the same driver now.

Comment: With your link and after entering the name of my device, the website https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule appears. Why are there 3 Downloads and do I need all of them? When I click the first one and then "Accept" 5 Downloads appear. What's the difference between .rpm and .deb files? When do I need the last one (epson-inkjet-printer-201101w-1.0.0-1lsb3.2.src.rpm) because no processor type and no information on whether 32-bit or 64-bit is part of the filename?

Comment: The first one is the printer driver. 2nd is an utility to show ink levels and some maintenance. 3rd is a scanner driver. For Ubunu you need a `deb` package. `i386` is 32-bit, `amd64` is 64-bit.

Comment: On the website https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=DE&CN2=&DSCMI=97917&DSCCHK=d1a765757a26d6fa274fd2b95618972e27d6d51c after clicking "Akzeptieren" (accept terms of service...) is "Package Download Page" the right one for drivers or "Source File Download Page"?

Comment: That is for scanner. The right one is "Package Download Page".

Comment: I downloaded the files. Can these deb packages be installed manually on my system in case they are needed for example after an upgrade etc. if the driver isn't installed automatically or not working for some reason?

Comment: Sure, you can, why not? That's what I am always doing. Scanner drivers don't seem to be installed automatically.

Comment: You are a very helpful individual and very familiar with linux issues! I don't want to overdo it but if you have time, you can take a look at my 2 other Ask Ubuntu questions. Maybe you could help there, too!